# One line code for array of content to convert dictionary of values in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
data =  [ "         64               40               64              41   144      144\r\n", "         68               40               64              41   144      144\r\n", "         72               41               64              41   144      144\r\n", "         76               41               64              41   144      144\r\n", "        128               41               64              41   144      144\r\n", "        132               41               64              42   144      144\r\n", "        136               41               64              42   144      144\r\n", "        140               41               64              42   144      144\r\n"]
re = /\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/
dlm = []
data.each do |arr|
    val = arr.scan(re).flatten.reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
    unless val.empty?
      d = {}
      d["x"] = val[0]
      d["y"] = val[1]
      d["z"] = val[2]
      d["m"] = val[3]
      d["n"] = val[4]
      d["o"] = val[5]
      dlm.append(d)
     end
end
```

I need the above code in one line with ruby. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Please edit to show the desired result (return value) for your example. You should always do that when giving examples in SO questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write that as follows.

```
keys = ["x", "y", "m", "n", "o"]
data.map { |s| keys.zip(s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)).to_h }
  #=> [{"x"=>64,  "y"=>40, "m"=>64, "n"=>41, "o"=>144},
  #    {"x"=>68,  "y"=>40, "m"=>64, "n"=>41, "o"=>144},
  #    {"x"=>72,  "y"=>41, "m"=>64, "n"=>41, "o"=>144},
  #    {"x"=>76,  "y"=>41, "m"=>64, "n"=>41, "o"=>144},
  #    {"x"=>128, "y"=>41, "m"=>64, "n"=>41, "o"=>144},
  #    {"x"=>132, "y"=>41, "m"=>64, "n"=>42, "o"=>144},
  #    {"x"=>136, "y"=>41, "m"=>64, "n"=>42, "o"=>144},
  #    {"x"=>140, "y"=>41, "m"=>64, "n"=>42, "o"=>144}]
```

You could of course remove the line defining `keys` by substituting out the variable `keys` in the second line.

Here are the steps for the first two elements of `data` that are passed to the block by `map`:

```
s = data[0]
  #=> "      64            40            64           41   144   144\r\n"
a = s.scan(/\d+/)
  #=> ["64", "40", "64", "41", "144", "144"]
b = a.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [64, 40, 64, 41, 144, 144]
c = keys.zip(b)
  #=> [["x", 64], ["y", 40], ["m", 64], ["n", 41], ["o", 144]]
c.to_h
  #=> {"x"=>64, "y"=>40, "m"=>64, "n"=>41, "o"=>144}
```

```
s = data[1]
  #=> "      68            40            64           41   144   144\r\n"
a = s.scan(/\d+/)
  #=> ["68", "40", "64", "41", "144", "144"]
b = a.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [68, 40, 64, 41, 144, 144]
c = keys.zip(b)
  #=> [["x", 68], ["y", 40], ["m", 64], ["n", 41], ["o", 144]]
c.to_h
  #=> {"x"=>68, "y"=>40, "m"=>64, "n"=>41, "o"=>144}
```

Comment: One less level of parentheses nesting: `data.map { |s| s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).zip(keys).map(&:reverse).to_h }`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby does not require line breaks. They are always optional and can always be replaced with either whitespace, an expression separator, or a keyword.

Which means you can *always* write *any* Ruby program in one line by simply removing the line breaks:

```ruby
data =  [ "         64               40               64              41   144      144\r\n", "         68               40               64              41   144      144\r\n", "         72               41               64              41   144      144\r\n", "         76               41               64              41   144      144\r\n", "        128               41               64              41   144      144\r\n", "        132               41               64              42   144      144\r\n", "        136               41               64              42   144      144\r\n", "        140               41               64              42   144      144\r\n"]; re = /\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/; dlm = []; data.each do |arr| val = arr.scan(re).flatten.reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i); unless val.empty? then d = {}; d["x"] = val[0]; d["y"] = val[1]; d["z"] = val[2]; d["m"] = val[3]; d["n"] = val[4]; d["o"] = val[5]; dlm.append(d) end end
```

There you go. Your code in one line.